# Android emulator control buttons (back, home, recent) are not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

I have installed android emulator through terminal

```
system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64 | 10 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image
```

I have installed this sdk with the help of `sdkmanager` and I have created an `avd` with `avdmanager`. I am able to run my application in the avd, but back, home, task buttons are not working, there was no effect by clicking that buttons. I have been working on this and most of the answers suggested either enable `focus on mouse hover` feature in `gnome-tweaks` or edit `hw.keyboard` parameter in `android/avd/config.ini` file. `focus on mouse hover` feature didn't help me and I dont have `avd` folder in my `android` directory.
I am using `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`

Answer (score 7):

Go to AVD Manager and do a 'Cold boot'

Answer (score 1):

Just run into this, and after all research the steps that finally worked for me were:

- Edit `config.ini` file and set `hw.keyboard = yes` (let `hw.mainKeys` and `hw.dPad` be `no` as default)
- In the emulator, go to Settings screen > System > Gestures > System Navigation (using Pixel/Android 13.0 image) and select "3-Button Navigation"
- Restart emulator

[image: Settings screen]

Answer (score 0):

The "cold boot" did the trick for me as well. For those who don't use Android Studio or AVD Manager UI, you can change this in the `config.ini` of the avd image.

The relevant properties:

```ini
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot = no
fastboot.forceColdBoot = yes
fastboot.forceFastBoot = no
```

On my Windows machine, that file can be found in `C:\Tools\AndroidSDK\.android\avd\android_11_sdk_30.avd\config.ini`, but of course this will vary on other machines...

Answer (score -1):

Just goto the

> C:\Users\YourUserName\.android\avd\Pixel_4_API_30.avd\

This folder have `.lock` file just delete it but before deleting it close the emulator and then delete it.

Restart your emulator and its working fine.

Comment: Still not work after delete it